# White noise sound vs harmonic sound reverb

Tags: sound, acoustics, measurement

I use a microphone array to localise a sound source in a small lecture theatre. 
I tested it  with white noise and a bird noise source. I found out that the white noise source give very good results. However, bird noise give noisy results.

My question is: does white noise produce less reverb and echo noise?
If so, why is that?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you are using as a sound source and how far away the microphones are, things like that? And is it a resonant sound with the bird noise?

Comment: are you trying to get the space's Reverberation time and sound characteristics? such as waterfall diagrams?

Comment: Reverb is signal spectral dependend. since your bird noise have a different energy spectrum as white noise it gives a different result.
White noise have o lot of hight frequency energy. bird noise i don't know??
You can test with a chirp to see where in the spectrum the lecture theatre gives most reverb.
Probably is a lot of energy in the spectrum of the bird noise